# asset.thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue() crashing on iPad only

Tags: ios, swift

I have an imagePicker which works on iPhone but when trying the same on iPad, it crashes.

The crash happens on this line

```
asset.thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue()
```

Anyone know the reason why this is on iPad only?

The thumbnail is an explicit optional and then unretainedValue must be causing the crash.

It crashes with an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` INVOP

**UPDATE:**

After trying the `takeRetainedValue()` function it crashes the same way.

For some reason the thumbnail is not being created when loading the image from the iPad only. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

[iPhone app run on iPad can not get asset thumbnail](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43601)